# Laravel + Vue.js API POST Error in cpanel Subdirectory Deployment: 'The POST method is not supported"

Tags: php, vuejs3, laravel-10

I'm facing an issue with my Laravel + Vue.js project when trying to send an API request to /api/questions-answer for email sending. The project is deployed in a **subdirectory** of a domain, and I'm encountering an error:

> **"*The POST method is not supported for route cost-calculator/api/questions-answer. Supported methods: GET, HEAD*"**

Laravel API route: Route::post('/questions-answer', [QuestionAnswerController::class, 'store']);

```
Vue.js Axios request:
let response = await axios.post('api/questions-answer', {
    first_name: firstName,
    last_name: lastName,
    email: email,
});
```

Everything of the project works fine except the post route error.
The post route works fine when deployed in the main directory or a subdomain.
The issue arises when deploying in a subdirectory (e.g., https://example.com/cost-calculator).

Adjusted: Axios base URL to axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://example.com/cost-calculator';.
Verified that Laravel API route is correctly defined.

How can I properly configure the API request in a subdirectory deployment?
Are there specific adjustments needed in Laravel's routing or Vue.js Axios configuration?

Laravel version: 10.40.0
Vue.js version: 3

Comment: I think it could be a sort of CORS issue (of the preflight option), what error can you see in the console and/or network tab in addition to 'method is not supported'? could you test your API directly with Postman (without a browser)?

Comment: i tested api with postman and it show the same error that is "405 Method Not Allowed"